# Segments every month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I ned help.

I have 3 tables:
1. Companies
2. Orders
3. Tickets from orders
I have to show table in power bi, in which the company segment will be displayed monthly. 
Data, conditions and result in [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jVD7kSxO0KemQxwRGLBIdDl4Mjy6PA_Jgnq6EqwRbXc/edit?usp=sharing)
conditions [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRM6D.png)
I will be glad to any prompt

Answer (score 0):

Add a calculated column in the table companies

```
   Column = If(
     DATEDIFF(
         company[created_date].[Date],TODAY(),MONTH) < 1 
      , "New"
      , IF( 
          Calculate(
              COUNTROWS(tickets), 
              DATEDIFF(orders[date_issued] ,EARLIER(company[created_date]),MONTH) = 
              0) <= 1 
        ,"Sleep"
        //Add here a condition about the frequency
        ,"Business"
      )
 )
```

To add a calculated column you can first go to see your table by clicking on this icon
[image]

once you've clicked on the right table you can add a column in the home tab
[image]

And you can write the code in the blank area like this

[image]

Comment: my friend, could you show it in pbix file? what i have to use in matrix table such a column? pbix file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wJZFZXEGemASYWL3OBmANF7nMLAEyZiI/view?usp=sharing
and how i can write condition about the frequency?

Comment: I add print screen to the response to show how to add measure
And can you give more information about what frequency is exactly and how to use to calculate this frequency to adapt the function

Comment: frequency -  months, when tickets were buy / months from created.
Example: company created 1 january. It bought: in january, march and june.
frequency for january - 100%, for february - 50%, for march - 2/3=67%, for apr - 2/4=50%, for may - 2/5=40%, for june - 3/6=50%.

Could you edit pbix file?

Comment: last ticket created for month.
For march I use tickets from january and march (2 months), no from june. 
from january to march there are 3 months.
So march I devide 2 / 3 = 67%

Comment: And if the company buy more than one ticket in the month you count as only 1 for the month ?